# Is it possible to set MYSQL_PS1 with colors without messing up prompt line width calculation?

Tags: mysql, prompt, ansi-escape

Consider the following setting for `MySQL_PS1`:

```
GREEN="$(echo -e '\033[01;32m')"
BLUE="$(echo -e '\033[01;34m')"
RESET="$(echo -e '\033[00m')"
export MYSQL_PS1="${GREEN}STAGING-\\d${BLUE} >${RESET} "
```

When I start `mysql`, and type a command that is longer than the visual line length, it wraps without a new line, overwriting the beginning of line.

I tried the `\[ \]` trick mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/24422) from here.

```
export MYSQL_PS1="\[${GREEN}\]STAGING-\\d\[${BLUE}\] >\[${RESET}\] "
```

Unfortunately, it produced this prompt instead of correctly excluding the escape characters from the line length.

```
] >\[\]  >[\] ]   >\[\] ]STAGING-\d\[\] >\[\] STAGING-messenger[\] >\[\]
```

Is there a way to set colors in `MYSQL_PS1` without messing up the estimated line length?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/397183/mysql-command-line-color-prompt#comment1157771_609782), which I will repost here.

The correct incantation is to surround the escape sequence with `\001` and `\002`.

```
GREEN="$(echo -e '\001\033[01;32m\002')"
BLUE="$(echo -e '\001\033[01;34m\002')"
RESET="$(echo -e '\001\033[00m\002')"
export MYSQL_PS1="${GREEN}STAGING-\\d${BLUE} >${RESET} "
```